# Fasting and accidental swallowing (urgent need for answer)

Tags: ramadan

I put on a lip balm and tried my best not to get it in my tongue but I felt a bit of the flavoured taste while my throat was dry and swallowed but with little to no saliva. Is my fast valid or broken???