# Is it possible in Islam to voluntarily receive other peoples sins?

Tags: sin

Is it possible in Islam to voluntarily receive other peoples sins, freeing them?

The immediate reason I ask is [I need urgent help](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/83030/55518) .

And if it is possible, what is the way to do it?